# Failed to retrieve data for content id - after deleting a property

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm currently working on a project using Umbraco and I ended up with this error after something went wrong when editing an Archetype property. The Archetype object cleared all of its properties for some reason and I deleted it with the intention to re-create it. After deleting it, my root-node and some of its subnodes just stopped working. Whenever I click on them to edit them, the error belows shows up.

The thing is, I only used that Archetype property on the "frontpage"-node, so why the "frontpage"-node's siblings started erroring too, I have no idea about.

I hope you can help me, I can simply not figure out what to do and only my webhost has database backups, and they require a fee in order to restore it.

```
Received an error from the server
    Failed to retrieve data for content id 1082 

 Mapping types:
 Property -> ContentPropertyDisplay
 Umbraco.Core.Models.Property -> Umbraco.Web.Models.ContentEditing.ContentPropertyDisplay

 Destination path:
 IEnumerable`1[0]

 Source value:
 Umbraco.Core.Models.Property

EXCEPTION DETAILS:

AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 

 Mapping types:
 Property -> ContentPropertyDisplay
 Umbraco.Core.Models.Property -> Umbraco.Web.Models.ContentEditing.ContentPropertyDisplay

 Destination path:
 IEnumerable`1[0]

 Source value:
 Umbraco.Core.Models.Property
STACKTRACE:

ved AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
   ved AutoMapper.Mappers.EnumerableMapperBase`1.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   ved AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
   ved AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, Action`1 opts)
   ved AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
   ved AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
   ved Umbraco.Web.Models.Mapping.TabsAndPropertiesResolver.ResolveCore(IContentBase content)
   ved AutoMapper.ValueResolver`2.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
   ved AutoMapper.PropertyMap.<ResolveValue>b__6(ResolutionResult current, IValueResolver resolver)
   ved System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)
   ved AutoMapper.PropertyMap.ResolveValue(ResolutionContext context)
   ved AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap propertyMap)
   ved AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   ved AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   ved AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
   ved AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, Action`1 opts)
   ved AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
   ved AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
   ved Umbraco.Web.Editors.ContentController.GetById(Int32 id)
   ved lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   ved System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   ved System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   ved System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- Afslutningen på staksporingen fra den tidligere placering, hvor undtagelsen blev udløst ---
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   ved System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console? Also try to add a label datatype with the same alias as the archetype before

Comment: No errors besides the above. But I managed to find a backup of the files which I then restored, which actually ended up fixing it, even though I had no database backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by restoring a backup of the files. As I mentioned, I had no database backup, but I did have a backup of the Umbraco files, just had no idea that would actually fix it considering it was a datatype screwing me over.

Comment: Properly because you restored App_data folder